# I want to calculate area of different shape on python

Tags: python, area

The user input "circle 3.5" or "rectangle 3 5"  or "trapezoid 3 5 7" (for the number decide by user) and output the area. Below is the code, but it can not run.

```
s=input("Input the shape and number:")
# for example,
# s="rect:5 3"
# s="cir:3.5"
#s="trapz:3 5 7"
cmd, para=s.split(:)
print(f"{cmd}->{para}")

if cmd == 'cir':
    r = float(para)
    print(f"area={r*r*3.14}")
elif cmd == 'rect':
    sw, sh = int(para.split())
    print(f"area={sw*sh}")
elif cmd == 'trapz':
    ul, bl, h = int(para.split())
    print(f"area={(ul+bl)*h/2}")
else:
    print("wrong input")
```

Thanks for the comments. I also try the other way to solve this question.The codes are:

```
s=input("Input the shape and number:").split()

if s[0]=="cir":
    r = float(s[1])
    print(f'area={r*r*math.pi}')
elif s[0]=="rect":
    sw, sh = int(s[1]), int(s[2])
    print(f"area={sw*sh}")
elif s[0]=="trapz":
    ul, bl, h = int(s[1]), int(s[2]), int(s[3])
    print(f'area={(ul+bl)*h/2}')
else:
    print('Wrong input!')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You have a few issues in your code.  1) You're overwriting your variable ```s```.  2) try ```s.split(":")```   Please post the full error traceback.

Comment: Curly bracket is not for grouping, use parentheses.

Comment: @Marichyasana Curly brackets here are not used for grouping, they are part of the f-string syntax.

Comment: @Ryo kamili Use `math.pi` instead of 3.14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues with your code. You are assigning a value to s after the user provides their input. I am assuming these were just for your own reference, so I commented them out.

Since `s.split()` will convert your string into a list, you need to make sure you are assigning portions of your list to the right number of variables. You can't directly assign two variables to a three element list. So I have used `s.split(':')[0], s.split(':')[1:]` to get the first element of the list, then the remaining elements of the same list.

Also you cannot apply `int()` to a list as Python won't do that much magic for you, so you need to use a list comprehension instead.

```
s=input("Input the shape and number:")
# s="rect:5:3"
# s="cir:3.5"
# s="trapz:3 5 7"
cmd, para=s.split(':')[0], s.split(':')[1:]
print(cmd,"->",para)

if cmd=='cir':
    r = float(para[0])
    print(f"arear={r*r*3.14}")
elif cmd=='rect':
    sw, sh =[int(x) for x in para]
    print(f"area={sw*sh}")
elif cmd=='trapz':
    ul, bl, h = [int(x) for x in para]
    print(f"area={(ul+bl)*h/2}")
else:
    print("wrong input")
```

Sample outputs:

```
Input the shape and number:rect:5:3
rect -> ['5', '3']
area=15

Input the shape and number:cir:3.5
cir -> ['3.5']
arear=38.465

Input the shape and number:trapz:3:5:7
trapz -> ['3', '5', '7']
area=28.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I know where the reason is.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just apply `int` to a list

```
s=input("Input the shape and number:")
cmd, para=s.split(":")
print(cmd,"->",para)

if cmd=='cir':
    r = float(para)
    print(f"arear={r*r*3.14}")
elif cmd=='rect':
    sw, sh = (float(x) for x in para.split())
    print(f"area={sw*sh}")
elif cmd=='trapz':
    ul, bl, h = (float(x) for x in para.split())
    print(f"area={(ul+bl)*h/2}")
else:
    print("wrong input")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is multiple. For instance, you are trying to pass multiple values to `int()` and `float()`, which take and return single values. To apply `int` to a list you can use the `map` function otherwise it won't run.

I would suggest you look at the error messages you receive when trying to run this code. It is a valuable practice to do as you learn Python.

Comment: *you are trying to assign an int and float, which are single values, to several variables*, `para.split()` will return a list of two values which when assigned to `sw, sh` will be unpacked into these two variables . The actual problem is `int` does not accept a list a must be called separately for each item in that list.

Comment: @AmalK I edited my comment to be clearer. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for input and assigning their answer to the 's' variable here:

```
s=input("Input the shape and number:")
```

then you are changing the value of the s variable to a different string three times.

```
s="rect:5:3"
s="cir:3.5"
s="trapz:3 5 7"
```

After this line of code the s variable is equal to the string: "trapz: 3 5 7" regardless of what the user enters.

Also, the colon used as the 'split' argument needs to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
s=input("Input the shape and number:")
s = s.split(':')
cmd, para= s[0], s[1:] # <---- added this
print(cmd,"->",para)

if cmd=='cir':
    r = float(para[0])
    print(f"arear={r*r*3.14}")
elif cmd=='rect':
    sw, sh =list(map(int, para)) #<---- added this
    print(f"area={sw*sh}")
elif cmd=='trapz':
    ul, bl, h = list(map(int, para))
    print(f"area={(ul+bl)*h/2}")
else:
    print("wrong input")
```

---

```
Input the shape and number:trapz:3:5:7
trapz -> ['3', '5', '7']
area=28.0


Input the shape and number:rect:3:5
rect -> ['3', '5']
area=15

Input the shape and number:cir:4.6
cir -> ['4.6']
arear=66.44239999999999
```